# Splitting a complex string in R

Tags: r, string, split

I have a dataset that contains full names of people, and I have to split it into first, last, and other names. I was about to use tidyr::separate, but the thing is that the dataset contains strings of various lengths: some people have only two names (first & last), some three or even more, and some have complex names (e.g. Dutch 'van Gogh') or names with titles ('Brown CFA'). Any ideas how to go about that?

Extract:

```
> database$Full_Name[15:25]
 [1] "David Regan"                  "Izaque Iuzuru Nagata"        
 [3] "Christian Schmit de la Breli" "Peter Doyle"                 
 [5] "Hans R.Bruetsch"              "Marcus Reichel"              
 [7] "Per-Axel Koch"                "Louis Van der Walt"          
 [9] "Mario Adamek"                 "Ugur Tozsekerli"             
[11] "Judit Ludvai"
```

Comment: If your dataset have complex names, what are the rules for splitting?  If anything works, then `strsplit(database$Full_Name, ' ')`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yes and no. `sapply()` works best of all I tried, but I'm looking for a more accurate solution, if there is one. The thing is that `sapply()` and similar function pick up only first and last words of a string, where in my dataset first words could be titles like 'Dr' and last names sometimes are more than one word (e.g. 'van Gogh'). But if you don't think there is a script to solve that, we can possibly close the topic.

Comment: Yeah, what's the hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to go with a brand-spankin new, [V8-infused github package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/humanparser), this should work:

```
# YOU WILL NEED TO DO THIS FIRST!
# devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/humanparser")

library(humanparser)

parse_name("John Smith Jr.")

## $firstName
## [1] "John"
## 
## $suffix
## [1] "Jr."
## 
## $lastName
## [1] "Smith"
## 
## $fullName
## [1] "John Smith Jr."


full_names <- c("David Regan", "Izaque Iuzuru Nagata",
                "Christian Schmit de la Breli", "Peter Doyle", "Hans R.Bruetsch",
                "Marcus Reichel", "Per-Axel Koch", "Louis Van der Walt",
                "Mario Adamek", "Ugur Tozsekerli", "Judit Ludvai" )


parse_names(full_names)

## Source: local data frame [11 x 4]
## 
##    firstName     lastName                     fullName middleName
## 1      David        Regan                  David Regan         NA
## 2     Izaque       Nagata         Izaque Iuzuru Nagata     Iuzuru
## 3  Christian  de la Breli Christian Schmit de la Breli     Schmit
## 4      Peter        Doyle                  Peter Doyle         NA
## 5       Hans   R.Bruetsch              Hans R.Bruetsch         NA
## 6     Marcus      Reichel               Marcus Reichel         NA
## 7   Per-Axel         Koch                Per-Axel Koch         NA
## 8      Louis Van der Walt           Louis Van der Walt         NA
## 9      Mario       Adamek                 Mario Adamek         NA
## 10      Ugur   Tozsekerli              Ugur Tozsekerli         NA
## 11     Judit       Ludvai                 Judit Ludvai         NA
```

It's based on [this node.js module](https://github.com/chovy/humanparser) and uses the V8 package in the background to do all the dirty work with the `parseName` function from that module (yes, it's R calling JavaScript to Get 'er Done). Someone should really port that code to R at some point, though, since Python has a similar module.

Comment: Some feedback: it reverses the order of middle names (fullName Alfredo Francesco Luigi Orelli, middleName Luigi Francesco) which is not bad but slightly weird. There are also some minot oddities with name parsing (e.g. it puts 'van den' as a middle name, even though it's a part of certain Dutch surnames), but I guess you can't fit it for every individual case.

Comment: this one - https://github.com/Ironholds/humaniformat - should be done by tomorrow and may perform better in the long run as it's Rcpp-based vs javascript-based (Oliver is a super gd chap).

Comment: For what it's worth the Rcpp-based one handles middle names in the correct order and is now capable of parsing, for example, "Laura van den Berg" while recognising "van den Berg" as the surname.

Comment: When I tried parsing with `humaniformat::parse_names` the session got aborted :(

Comment: @OliverKeyes will no doubt have it stable soon (it took him less than a day to get it to where it is now :-)

Comment: @PavelKirjanas could you email me the data it segfaults on? oliver [at] wikimedia [dot] org. Happy to fix it up for you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("humanparser")
```

This one works best! Thanks, Oliver!

Comment: ARGH. and i asked him to write that, too. There goes 15pts down the drain ;-)

Comment: Okay, back to you ;D I'll buy you a beer too ;)))